# "The type or namespace name does not exist in the namespace" while building

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reference, visual-studio-2013, namespaces

I'm getting the error "The type or namespace name does not exist in the namespace" in one of our test projects lately.

Things I have already verified:

- **Spelling:** Everything is spelled correctly. Inside the files there is no error and I can navigate to the Methods via Ctrl+F12 normally
- **Target Framework:** The target framework of every project is set to .NET Framework 4. So no mismatches between the project and the referenced project
- **Project Reference:** I double checked if the project reference was added and even deleted and readded it

Is there anything else I can check?
Has anyone of you encountered the same problem and was able to solve it?

Thanks in advance

PS: I'm using VS2013 and ReSharper

Comment: Check the type is public, See if you can reference it in a clean project, Check using statements included

Comment: Might also be a problem when mixing x86/x64/AnyCPU

Comment: @Sayse: yes the type is public. I have referenced the project in a clean new project and everything works fine and builds successfully... the using statements are included and correct

Comment: @stijn:  every project is set to x86 so there shouldnt be a mix :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the problem.
The referenced project (client) had a new reference to Bcl...
Apperently every project that references the client needs to reference Bcl too now.

Thanks for all your help!